# setting html image input into enable disable modes when check box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I have written following code to set the status of the image button to enable disables modes
using JQuery.

following is the code for check box in yii format

```
<?php echo CHtml::CheckBox('TermsAgreement','', array ('checked'=>'unchecked','value'=>'on',    )); ?>
```

this code produce input element as follows.

```
<input value="on" type="checkbox" name="TermsAgreement" id="TermsAgreement">
```

Then i have image button code as follows in yii format

```
 <?php echo CHtml::imageButton('/mactorget/images/procceed.png', array ('disabled'=>false, 'id'=>'procceed')); ?>
```

Above code produce following image button input element

```
<input id="procceed" src="/mactorget/images/procceed.png" type="image" name="yt0" value="submit">
```

Now i want to set the enable disable modes of image button based on checkbox status.

to do that i have written following code sample

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
                'change',
                '$("#TermsAgreement").change(function () { if($("#TermsAgreement").attr("checked")){ document.getElementById("procceed").getAttribute("disabled")=false; }else{ document.getElementById("procceed").getAttribute("disabled")=true; }});'
);
```

but this does not set the status of the image button element.

Could anybody having experience/knowledge in this issue share your ideas with me. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved version of your code:

```
$("#TermsAgreement").change(function() {
    $("#procceed").attr("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

All together:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
    'change',
    '$("#TermsAgreement").change(function() { $("#procceed").attr("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked")); });'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setAttribute`.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattribute.asp

You are using jQuery, so you can give `$("#procceed").attr("disabled", true) and`$("#procceed").attr("disabled", false);